# How do you make a button link to a website in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

How would you make a button in cocoa when clicked open a web page?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just like what Chuck said, look up [this](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace%5FClass/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURL:).
For example, if I wanted to link to Google.com, You would do the following:

```
- (IBAction)goToLink:(id)sender
{
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]];
}
```

Comment: Says NSURLURLString is Undecalared. Why?

Comment: I meant to put 'NSURLURLWithString Undeclared'. Why is this happening?

Comment: @Joshua make sure there's a space between NSURL and URLWithString

Answer (score 9):

Assuming you mean opening the page in the user's default browser (not in a web view inside your app), see [-[NSWorkspace openURL:]](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/openURL:)

Comment: From one of the samples listed on the page smorgan linked to: [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:completeURLStr]];

Comment: How would you link it to a button?

Comment: Except if this is a remote webpage, you would use URLWithString, rather than fileURLWithPath:.

NSURL is well documented if you need more information: http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Put the call in your button's action method; the same way you make anything else happen when a button is clicked. If you aren't familiar with the basics of hooking up UI to code using interface builder, try a tutorial like http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCTutorial/01Introduction/01Introduction.html

Comment: So I create an action, which I will link to the button, but what will I put in the .m file to explain the Action?

Comment: That's where you call openURL: from.